# how to send email from a website hosted on s3

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a website hosted on S3 on amazon web services. I want to receive emails on my gmail account from  the visitors of my website if they wish to contact me. I'm confused with the steps for the setup as I tried working around with SES on amazon web service but am completely off tracK I believe.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a email-form written in PHP. I added my address but it doesn't work, so wanted to start a fresh with this issue.

Answer (score 3):

S3 doesn't support any server-side code, such as PHP - so you can't use server-side logic to send an email.

There are two options:

1. Implement a mailto: link that will cause the user to open their mail client when then click on it.
2. Use a third-party mail service that supports a REST API, and implement that in Javascript. You can use something like  [SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html), [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/) or [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/).

Each of these services can be called using Javascript. Implement your mail form page to make an API call to these services to deliver the comment to your inbox.

Comment: better yet, write a Lambda function your html form can POST to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use AWS Lambda with Amazon API Gateway to create a serverless backend and use Amazon Simple Email Service to send an e-mail. A good tutorial below:

[Create Dynamic Contact Forms for S3 Static Websites Using AWS Lambda, Amazon API Gateway, and Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/create-dynamic-contact-forms-for-s3-static-websites-using-aws-lambda-amazon-api-gateway-and-amazon-ses/)

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but as others have said you can setup a AWS Lambda function at an API Gateway to use AWS SES to send an email. You post your html form to it (or some other service you create on an actual server you control) and send an email via some Gmail SDK/API There's quite a few tutorials for this online.

You can also use a free third-party service like [Formspree](https://formspree.io/) to create an html form that posts to their servers and they will send you an email to wherever you specify.